# Show taxonomy children in parent

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a block view that only displays the taxonomy terms in a vocabulary. However I would like to have a link generated in that block with an "ALL" option. So I created a new taxonomy entry, which is the parent of all other terms.

However if I go to the taxonomy parent, the children aren't shown, only if the nodes are set to the parent value explicitly.

For example:

```
All (tid=1)
-Shirts (tid=2)
--Small (tid=3)
--Big (tid=4)
-Shoes (tid=5)
```

So if I were to go to `http://mysite.com/taxonomy/term/1` I want it to show all nodes in terms 2 and 5 (would be ideally to have 3 and 4 show up also, but not mandatory).

I am using Drupal 7.x

Comment: I don't think you can accomplish this without views.

Comment: with Views module you can do that easy, with contextual filter, `Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) ` and set your depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [`taxonomy_get_children()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/7)?

> Finds all children of a term ID.